# Prove that $I_X: X \to X$ defined by $I_X(x) = x$ is a bijection

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ be a set. For a function $I_X: X \to X$ defined by $I_X(x) = x$, prove that $I_X$ is a bijection.

This seems relatively easy to make sense of if you have knowledge of what a bijection is, but I am struggling to formally prove it. How might I do so?

Comment: What the heck?  You mean the identity function?

Comment: yeah Identity function/map/ whatever else its called

Comment: one-to-one:  $x=y$ implies $x=y$.  Done.

Comment: Do you mean $I_X$ instead of $IX$?

Comment: @FrenzyLi Yes, sorry I'm struggling to find how to format it as such

Comment: @Questioner To format it that way, write `$I_X$`.

Comment: @Questioner The markup you're looking for is `$I_X:X\to X$`.  For more symbols, you can look it up in [Detextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and the [referece](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @FrenzyLi Yes, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bijection is injective and surjective.

**Injective**: Assume that $I_X(x) = I_X(y)$. Applying the definition of $I_X$, it follows that $x = I_X(x) = I_X(y) = y$.  So, $I_X(x) = I_X(y)\implies x=y$, so this is injective.

**Surjective**: For any $y\in X$ (the codomain), we have that $y\in X$ (the domain) maps to $y$, meaning that $I_X(y) = y$.  So, $\forall x\in X, \exists y\in X$ s.t. $I_X(y)= x$ (just choose $y = x$), so this is surjective.

$I_X$ is injective and surjective, so is bijective.